# Is there a way to configure Emacs to never use a leading ~ whenever it needs to show me a path name?

Tags: filenames

In almost every situation I come across (e.g. in `*BufferList*`, in the pre-populated argument prefix for `find-file`, etc., etc.), Emacs uses a leading `~` in the paths to any files or directories under my `$HOME` directory.

I would like to stop Emacs from doing this<sup>1</sup>, and instead use the full explicit path, as in, e.g., `/home/yourstruly/foo/bar/baz` (and NOT `~/foo/bar/baz`).  Is there a way to configure Emacs to behave this way?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I work on many different systems throughout the day, each with a different value for `$HOME`.  In my notes for work I need to refer to paths in one or another of these `$HOME` directories, and it would not be helpful if I were to use a leading `~` when writing down such paths.  As a result I find myself constantly having to replace the leading `~` that Emacs insists on giving me with the actual value for the current `$HOME`.  I want to save myself from this recurring annoyance.</sup>

Comment: The question isn't clear. As you say, *"..., etc., etc."*. **In what contexts** do you want to show `~` converted to your home directory (explicitly)? Emacs has 8 zillion contexts where it might show you `~/...`. There is *no single option* to **always and everywhere** have it show you what `~` stands for. Maybe that's all the answer that you wanted: there's no way to tell Emacs to always substitute for `~`.

Comment: (You could advise function `abbreviate-file-name` to have it not expand `~` anywhere. But that would no doubt wreak havoc on Emacs behavior here, there, and everywhere.)

Comment: I think `(setq abbreviated-home-dir regexp-unmatchable)` might implement that approach without advising or otherwise overriding `abbreviate-file-name`.

Comment: @Drew: Honestly, I just can't think of any context or situation where I would distinctly prefer Emacs' current default behavior here.  *At best* I may be indifferent (e.g. in situations where (a) the `~`-prefixed value remains completely hidden from me, and (b) the presence of `~` has no further visible effects downstream).  Bottomline, I just can't come up with any useful restriction to what I wrote originally.  Also, I confess that I am really surprised to learn that this design decision is so fundamental to Emacs' operation that tampering with it would lead to widespread malfunction...

Comment: @Drew: I am inclined to try something along the lines of either your second comment (on `abbreviate-file-name`), or @phils' suggestion, but your remark about "wreak[ing] havoc" by this sort of thing does make me hesitate.  Could you give one or two examples of the ways things could break if I were to fiddle with `abbreviate-file-name`'s behavior?

Comment: Go ahead and try, if you like. I don't advise it, however. I expect that existing code depends on abbreviated names, in multiple places. IOW, it's likely not just about *your seeing such names*; it's about code expecting and using such names. @Phil's suggestion is likely better than advising the function, in this regard.

Comment: Are you running Emacsen on all the different systems and then trying to copy paths from them to another Emacs where you are editing your notes by `copy-and-paste`ing? If so, I would suggest a simple command that takes the path at point as argument, does an `expand-file-name` on it and copies it to your preferred copy-and-paste place, so that you can then paste it directly. That adds a keystroke, but there is no possibility of messing up anything (I suspect that @phils' suggestion will not mess up anything either, although reassuring yourself that it does not might take some work).